Every polynomial is an algebraic function? What about $x + \pi$?
In Wikipedia, an algebraic function is defined as a function $y = f(x)$ which can be written as the solution of the polynomial equation $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i(x) y^i = 0$ where $a_i(x)$ are polynomials in $x$ with integer coeffecients.
Also in Wikipedia, they say that any polynomial $p(x)$ is an algebraic function as it is the solution of the equation $y = p(x)$? My question is how is this true if $p(x) = x + \pi$ i.e. the coefficients of $p$ are transcendental numbers?

Well,  it is algebraic,  just not over the rationals.  It's algebraic over $\mathbb Q(\pi)$.

@lulu Ok little confusion here... so when 'algebraic functions' are defined, they must be defined over some field/ group? If so, then what is the meaning of the default version of 'algebraic function' i.e. when no field is mentioned?

Well,  absent context,  I'd suppose it meant the rationals or at least an extension of the rationals.  Certainly,  if the intent is to look at the possible field(s) of definition of the roots,  one ought to specify the field the coefficients live in.

Just to say,  the same " ambiguity" already exists for the term "polynomial ". One really ought to specify the field, or ring,  that the coefficients live in but in practice,  we often just speak of polynomials.
